# Constructor is not initializing a Scanner object

Tags: java

In the following code the constructor is not initializing the numFile Scanner. I added the contents of the constructor to the main method to make it work. If I do not do this a java.lang.NullPointerException is thrown. Would someone mind explaining why? Also, do I need to throw an IOException on the constructor?

Thanks for any helpful advice.

Tony

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountPositiveIntegers {

    static Scanner numFile;
    static String fileName;     // the name of the file in which the integers are stored
    static int number;          // holds the current number being read
    static int counter;         // a counter used to sum the number of positive integers


    public CountPositiveIntegers() throws IOException { 
        fileName ="D:\\Java\\Source\\numFile.dat"; 
        System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);   
        numFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName)); 
        number = 0; 
        counter = 0; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // numFile is not being initializing in the constructor
        fileName = "D:\\Java\\Source\\numFile.dat";
        numFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
        number = 0;
        counter = 0;

        if (numFile.hasNext()) {                    // check to see if there are any values in the file
            while (numFile.hasNextInt()) {      // reads in integers
                number = numFile.nextInt();
                if (number % 2 == 0 & number != 0) {
                    counter++;                  
                }
            }
            numFile.close();                            // close the file           

            // print to screen the number of even integers stored in the file
            System.out.println("There are " + counter
                    + " even numbers in this file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The file is empty.");
        }   

        System.exit(0); // cleanly exit the program
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `CountPositiveIntegers` class object.

Answer (score 3):

You must explicitly call the constructor to have it work. (You never create a `new CountPositiveIntegers()`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I completely missed that.

Comment: methods are not initialized using "new", they are initialized inside a class with a access modifier + return type + parameters. But I think you know that. Don't worry - everybody misses stuff, especially as a novice programmer.

Comment: @Tony : It looks like you got the answer. In that case, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

In fact you use only static variables, the constructor is not called, and such an object would have no non-static fields. An example of Object Oriented programming:

```
public class CountPositiveIntegers {

    Scanner numFile;
    String fileName;     // the name of the file in which the integers are stored


    public CountPositiveIntegers(String fname) throws IOException { 
        fileName = fname; 
        System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);   
        numFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName)); 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            CountPositiveIntegers obj = new CountPositiveIntegers("D:\\Java\\Source\\numFile.dat");
            int number = 0;          // holds the current number being read
            int counter = 0;         // a counter used to sum the number of positive integers

            if (obj.numFile.hasNext()) {                    // check to see if there are any values in the file
                while (obj.numFile.hasNextInt()) {      // reads in integers
                    number = obj.numFile.nextInt();
                    if (number % 2 == 0 & number != 0) {
                        counter++;                  
                    }
                }
                obj.numFile.close();                            // close the file           

                // print to screen the number of even integers stored in the file
                System.out.println("There are " + counter
                        + " even numbers in this file");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The file is empty.");
            }   

            System.exit(0); // cleanly exit the program
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CountPositiveIntegers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There is some new stuff in here so I will take my time and read it. I did write my code, and now it looks similar to this, and is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that when your program starts up, it does *not* create a new instance of the class in which `main` is executed and instead just runs the code in `main`.  Since your initialization code is in your constructor, it's never actually run, because you don't create an instance of the main class.

To fix this, I would strongly suggest having `main` create a new instance of the class that `main` resides in, then perform all your operations on that object, rather than making everything `static` and just performing the operations in `main` directly.  Your current approach is not particularly good design.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've rewritten the code so that the variables are no longer static, the 'if' statement and 'while' loop is now in its own methods, and I used 'new' to create the object (allowing the constructor to run) and used that to call the newly created method. Everything appears to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your CountPositiveIntegers class object.

You need to call your constructor explicitly otherwise a default constructor will be called by the compiler.

```
new CountPositiveIntegers();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I see now what I did wrong and have rewritten the code.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor will not be invoked unless you actually call it. The main method does not call the constructor implicitly because it is a `static` method.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you for taking the time to help.